# How to catch the error of file_get_contents() in php

Tags: php

How i can catch the error of the `file_get_contents()`?

I tried this :

```
if(!$contenido = file_get_contents($url))
{
  $save=false;
}
```

It did not work

Comment: What are the values of `$contenido` and `$url`

Comment: @SuperDJ inside `url` is the URL of images . to download and `$contenido `will have the downloaded image details that I will save  later in my File

Comment: Please post some more of your code. I assume by "It did not work", you mean, the  condition in your `if` clause does not evaluate to `true`?

Comment: At least in the sample code you gave, `$save=false` needs to have a semicolon: `$save=false;`

Comment: @TimoSta Yes it did not evaluate to true even though I am getting error    `Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.casas.com.pe/images/17504_2015010819.jpg) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!`

Comment: You know you should use `==` instead of `=` like you have now. What you have now says `$contenido is file_get_contents($url)`

Comment: @SuperDJ He loads the content into `$contenido`, which is perfectly fine. After that he does the evaluation whether `$contenido` is false. So far, so good. Some brackets would be helpful, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) returns `FALSE` on failure. You must check for that value with the `===` operator. If you wish to suppress the warning, you can use the [`@` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) in front of `file_get_contents()`.

```
$contenido = @file_get_contents($url);
if (contenido === FALSE) {
    $save=FALSE;
}
```

From the [`file_get_contents()` docs](http://php.net/file_get_contents):

> Warning
>   This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

Comment: I think he's talking about suppressing the `E_WARNING`

Comment: @Machavity ah, perhaps. I've updated my answer to include a note about that. Thanks.

Comment: @Asaph can we suppress the warning of getimagesize() funcion also just like that?

Comment: WARNING! This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the PHP manual

Answer (score 3):

In PHP 5.x you really can't. The best you can do is suppress the error using the dreaded `@` symbol. This is not considered good coding practice because you're turning off notices, but in this case there's no other option.

```
if(!$contenido = @file_get_contents($url))
```

You'll still get your return of `false` but no Warnings, etc.

As of [php-7](/questions/tagged/php-7) you will be able to [catch errors like that](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/engine_exceptions_for_php7)

Comment: Wait, really? I need to go test this.

Comment: You can set up a [custom error handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) in versions of PHP prior to 7 that can convert a Warning into an Exception

Answer (score 1):

On failure, [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) will return FALSE, but it will be accompanied by an error message. You can hide that error message, but still get returns FALSE, you need to use the '@' symbol before the function name.

Try this:

```
$url = "path/to/file";
$contents = @file_get_contents($url);
if ($contents !== FALSE) {
   // TODO
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.